# How do I create a ViewPager without margins?

Tags: android

Using the ViewPager view from the Android support library, the default setup shows one page at a time, with a large margin between each item - ie, if your view is about half the width of your activity there's space on either side, and as you swipe the next one in there's space there too.

ViewPagers have a method, setPageMargin(), that lets you specify an offset to adjust the margin size between pages, and I'm using it to specify a negative margin so that it pulls the pages closer together. However, obviously the amount you need to pull in these margins varies according to the screen dimensions.

So, I'm looking for a smarter way: is there a way to tell the ViewPager "I want no margins at all, making the views in my ViewPager butt up against each other"?

Thank you!

Comment: Post some code mate XML and Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a smarter way, but your way should work if all pages have the same width. Try something like this:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
// getActivity().getWindow... if inside a Fragment
yourViewPager.setPageMargin((yourPageWidth - dm.widthPixels) / 2);
```